# Bitnami cassandra application password

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, bitnami

I created bitnami cassandra on EC2.
[The documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/cassandra/) says that

> The administrator user name is cassandra and you can get the password from the server dashboard for your server.

But it is not found when I get the system log.
I do find though a message that says

> Not setting Bitnami application passwords

How to obtain the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more info: (default cassandra password is the same as application password)

https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/#how-to-find-application-credentials

if you check this picture, you can see where you need to look:

https://docs.bitnami.com/images/img/platforms/virtual-machine/app-credentials-1bc7e819.png

Comment: You are just posting the generic image for Drupal. This does not apply for casandra unfortunately.

Comment: I use the same bitnami Cassandra image and I recall it worked for me. 
[link](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/infrastructure/cassandra/#what-is-the-default-configuration)

_The administrator user name is cassandra and you can get the password from the server dashboard for your server._

_How To Find The Database Credentials?
Database username: cassandra.
Database password: The same as the application password. Find out how to obtain application credentials. -> link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

For the `bitnami-cassandra-3.10-0-linux-ubuntu-14.04.3-x86_64-ebs (ami-32a71751)` image,
I found

default username : `cassandra`

default password: `bitnami`

It is not as per the documentation. I hope it might help who were facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

If you launched the machine on EC2, you should follow this guide instead:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/

You also could check the password by accessing via SSH and running:

`sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/log/pre-start.log | grep "application password"`

User is `cassandra` by default.

I hope it helps